# Can't make properties work within nested methods

Tags: python

Im trying to create a class with some formatting options. But i can't figure out how to do it properly...

The code produced the following error:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'valuesonly'

```
class Testings(object):

    def format_as_values_only(self,somedata):
        buildstring=somedata.values()
        return buildstring

    def format_as_keys_only(self):
        pass

    def format_as_numbers(self):
        pass


    def get_data_method(self):
        self.data= {'2_testkey':'2_testvalue',"2_testkey2":"2_testvalue2"}

        @property
        def valuesonly(self):
            return format_as_values_only(self.data)

test=Testings()
print test.get_data_method().valuesonly
```

The important thing for me is to be able to get the formatters like: class.method.formatter or so...

Thanks a lot for any hints!

Comment: Why are you defining property within method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do things this way.  Methods are just functions defined directly inside a class block.  Your function is inside another function, so it's not a method.  The `property` decorator is useless except in a class block.

But, more fundamentally, function definitions just create local names, the same as variable assignments or anything else.  Your `valuesonly` function is not accessible *at all* from outside the `get_data_method` function, because nothing from within a function is accessible except its return value.  What you have done is no different than:

```
def get_data_method(self):
    a = 2
```

. . . and then expecting to be able to access the local variable `a` from outside the function.  It won't work.  When you call `get_data_method()`, you get the value `None`, because `get_data_method` doesn't return anything.  Anything you subsequently do with the result of `get_data_method()` is just operating on that same None value.

If you want to access things using the syntax you describe, you will need to make `get_data_method` return an object that has properties like `valuesonly`.  In other words, write another class that provides a `valuesonly` property, and have `get_data_method` return an instance of that class.  A rough outline (untested):

```
class DataMethodGetter(object):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent

    @property
    def valuesonly(self):
        return format_as_values_only(self.parent.data)

class Testings(object):
    # rest of class def here
    def get_data_method(self):
        self.data = {'blah': 'blah'}
        return DataMethodGetter(self)
```

However, you should think about why you want to do this.  It's likely to be simpler to set it up to just call `valuesonly` directly on the `Testing` object, or to pass a flag to `get_data_method`, doing something like `get_data_method(valuesonly=True)`.

Comment: Hi bren because im kind of a noob concerning oop how would you create the approach you mentioned. Calling another Class from within a method...thanks a lot!

Comment: @Jurudocs: I added an example.  But you should think about why you're doing it this way.  Unless you have a big and complicated set of conditions to handle with `get_data_method`, it's probably easier to handle it inside the original `Testings` class and just call methods directly on that.  Using a separate class is, as my example shows, fairly verbose.

Comment: thanks a lot! The problem i want to handel lies in the different formatting options...i guess i have to think about the whole design!

Answer (score 2):

`get_data_method` has no return value, so the result of `test.get_data_method()` is `None`. That's why you're getting that exception.

If you *really* want to do something like `test.get_data_method().valuesonly`, either define the `valuesonly` property on `Testings`, and have `get_data_method` return `self`, or have `get_data_method` return some new object with the properties that you want defined.